# Classification Problem from CodeSprint 2012 (Updated)

Tags: java

I've updated the previous version to be more object oriented as suggested.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * A class containing a single record. Each record contains the Quora answer
 * ID and the predictor vector. If the record is a training example then the
 * target classification is also included.
 */
private class Record {

  private final Vector predictor;
  private final double target;
  private final String answerId;

  /**
   * Constructor for test records
   */
  public Record(Vector predictor, String answerId) {
    this.predictor = predictor;
    this.answerId = answerId;
    this.target = 0;
  }

  /**
   * Constructor for training records
   */
  public Record(Vector predictor, String answerId, double target) {
    this.predictor = predictor;
    this.answerId = answerId;
    this.target = target;
  }

  public Vector getPredictor() {
    return predictor;
  }

  public double getTarget() {
    return target;
  }

  public String getAnswerId() {
    return answerId;
  }

}

/**
 * Class for storing a list of records. The constructor reads the records from
 * the training or test sections of the input file as appropriate
 */
private class RecordList extends ArrayList<Record> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private final int numFeatures; // number of features in predictor

  /**
   * Constructor which loads records from training part of input file
   * 
   * @param sc
   *          scanner to read training data from
   */
  public RecordList(Scanner sc) {
    String[] dimString = sc.nextLine().split("\\s");
    int numRecords = Integer.parseInt(dimString[0]);
    numFeatures = Integer.parseInt(dimString[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++) {
      Vector predictor = new Vector(numFeatures);
      String[] recordString = sc.nextLine().split("\\s");
      // read Quora answer ID
      String answerId = recordString[0];
      // read training targets and convert from -1/+1 to 0/1
      double target = (Double.parseDouble(recordString[1]) + 1) / 2;
      // read predictor vector
      for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < numFeatures; fIndex++) {
        String featureString = recordString[2 + fIndex];
        predictor.set(fIndex, Double.parseDouble(featureString
            .substring(featureString.indexOf(":") + 1)));
      }
      add(new Record(predictor, answerId, target));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Constructor which loads records from test part of input file
   * 
   * @param sc
   *          scanner from which test data will be read
   */
  public RecordList(Scanner sc, int numFeatures) {
    this.numFeatures = numFeatures;
    String[] dimString = sc.nextLine().split("\\s");
    int numRecords = Integer.parseInt(dimString[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++) {
      Vector predictor = new Vector(numFeatures);
      String[] recordString = sc.nextLine().split("\\s");
      // read Quora answer ID
      String answerId = recordString[0];
      // read predictor vector
      for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < numFeatures; fIndex++) {
        String featureString = recordString[1 + fIndex];
        predictor.set(fIndex, Double.parseDouble(featureString
            .substring(featureString.indexOf(":") + 1)));
      }
      add(new Record(predictor, answerId));
    }
  }

  public int getNumFeatures() {
    return numFeatures;
  }

}

/**
 * Class which supports normalization of records
 */
private class Normalizer {

  private final Vector mean;
  private final Vector varSqrt;

  /**
   * Constructor normalizes supplied recordList and calculates elementwise
   * mean and variance
   */
  public Normalizer(RecordList recordList) {

    // calculate mean of each feature
    mean = new Vector(recordList.getNumFeatures());
    for (Record record : recordList) {
      mean.add(record.getPredictor());
    }
    mean.divide(recordList.size());

    // normalize recordList by feature means
    for (Record record : recordList) {
      record.getPredictor().subtract(mean);
    }

    // calculate variance of each feature
    varSqrt = new Vector(recordList.getNumFeatures());
    Vector predictorSquared = new Vector(recordList.getNumFeatures());
    for (Record record : recordList) {
      predictorSquared.set(record.getPredictor());
      predictorSquared.elementwiseSquare();
      varSqrt.add(predictorSquared);
    }
    varSqrt.divide(recordList.size());
    varSqrt.sqrt();

    // normalize recordList by feature variances
    for (Record record : recordList) {
      record.getPredictor().divide(varSqrt);
    }

  }

  /**
   * Normalize a Vector using the mean and variance calculated from supplied
   * recordList during instantiation
   * 
   * @param vector
   *          Vector to be normalized
   */
  public void normalize(Vector vector) {
    vector.subtract(mean);
    vector.divide(varSqrt);
  }

}

/**
 * Class for training of a classifier
 */
private class Trainer {

  // training rate for stochastic gradient descent
  private final double trainingRate;

  public Trainer(double trainingRate) {
    this.trainingRate = trainingRate;
  }

  /**
   * Train logistic regression coefficients using provided test records
   */
  public void train(Classifier classifier, RecordList testRecords) {

    for (Record record : testRecords) {
      // classify test record
      double estimate = classifier.classify(record.getPredictor());
      // determine classification error
      double estError = estimate - record.getTarget();
      // update regression coefficients using SGD
      Vector deltaTheta = record.getPredictor().clone();
      deltaTheta.multiply(-estError * trainingRate / testRecords.size());
      classifier.getRegressionCoeffs().add(deltaTheta);
    }

  }

}

/**
 * A class which implements classification using logistic regression
 */
private class Classifier {

  // regression coefficients, trained using Trainer
  private final Vector regressionCoeffs;
  // normalizer used to normalize predictor vectors
  private final Normalizer normalizer;
  // number of features in predictor vector
  private final int numFeatures;

  /**
   * Instantiates a classifier with a particular training set. A normalizer
   * will be instantiated, storing the mean and variance of the training set
   * for future use during classification
   */
  public Classifier(RecordList trainingSet) {
    normalizer = new Normalizer(trainingSet);
    numFeatures = trainingSet.getNumFeatures();
    regressionCoeffs = new Vector(numFeatures);
  }

  /**
   * Classify a predictor vector
   * 
   * @param predictor
   *          predictor vector to be classified
   * @return soft classification
   */
  public double classify(Vector predictor) {
    Vector normalizedPredictor = predictor.clone();
    normalizer.normalize(normalizedPredictor);
    normalizedPredictor.multiply(regressionCoeffs);
    return sigmoid(normalizedPredictor.elementSum());
  }

  /**
   * Sigmoid function
   * 
   * @param z
   *          a double
   */
  private double sigmoid(double z) {
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-z));
  }

  /**
   * Return regression coefficients
   * 
   * @return regression coefficient vector
   */
  public Vector getRegressionCoeffs() {
    return regressionCoeffs;
  }

  /**
   * Run classification for a set of queries and output the result to
   * System.out
   * 
   * @param sc
   *          Scanner for reading queries
   */
  public void classifyQueries(Scanner sc) {
    RecordList classificationSet = new RecordList(sc, numFeatures);
    for (Record record : classificationSet) {
      // classify
      double classification = classify(record.getPredictor());
      // output result to System.out
      if (classification > 0.5) {
        System.out.printf("%s +1\n", record.getAnswerId());
      } else {
        System.out.printf("%s -1\n", record.getAnswerId());
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Here's an example of a typical run

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner sc; // input file
  if (args.length > 0) { // input stream from file (for testing)
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));
    sc = new Scanner(in);
  } else { // input streamed from System.in (used in competition)
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  }
  // run classification
  QuoraClassifier classifier = new QuoraClassifier();
  double trainingRate = 5.0;
  RecordList trainingSet = new RecordList(sc);
  Classifier classifier = new Classifier(trainingSet);
  Trainer trainer = new Trainer(trainingRate);
  trainer.train(classifier, trainingSet);
  classifier.classifyQueries(sc);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked briefly but this looks good. I would try to be more expressive with some of your variable names and break the methods up a little more. Also, I think you can get away without using clone.